# Lambda method reference to Function<F,T> throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, retrolambda

I am using Retrolambda for Android with Java 8 and I ran into a runtime fatal exception when saving a lambda method reference into Android's `Function<F,T>` interface throwing a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

After wasting some time checking my own code, I actually realized that this interface is using `javax.annotation.Nullable` which has been moved to another dependency, causing it to not display any compilation errors, but throwing the mentioned exception at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was just to create my own copy of the Function interface with the right Nullable import.